# How to run veins simulation on omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, veins

So I am new to veins and I am trying to learn how to use this framework. I started following this tutorial http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/ I reached the last step and everything was working fine. In the last step and when i tried to run the veins example form omnetpp I got the following error :

```
   <!> Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) 
         RSUExampleScenario.manager (id=6) at event #1, t=0: Connection to 
      TraCI server lost. Check your server's log. Error message: 10054: ]
        Unknown error.
```

In minGW I got the following error:

```
             Seed is 0
           Finding free port number...
          Claiming lock on port
        ...found port 34259
   Starting SUMO (Sumo/bin/sumo.exe -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 34259,  
          seed 0
     Releasing lock on port
     Cleaning up
     Result: "<?xml version="1.0"?>
      <status>
    <exit-code>-1</exit-code>
    <start>1466497048</start>
    <end>1466497048</end>
    <status>Could not start SUMO (Sumo/bin/sumo.exe -c erlangen.sumo.cfg):  
       [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified</status>
    <stdout><![CDATA[]]></stdout>
    <stderr><![CDATA[]]></stderr>
     </status>
```

Can someone please help. I am a beginner and I am facing some problems,Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You have asked `sumo-launchd.py` to run SUMO as `Sumo/bin/sumo.exe`, but your system cannot find the file specified. Most likely, you need to run SUMO more like this `/c/Users/user/src/sumo-0.25.0/bin/sumo.exe` (depending on where you put `sumo.exe`)